# Sort data using DataView

Tags: c#, winforms, dataview

I have a DataGridView with column Remarks (Passed, Failed). For example, I want to show all the records Failed in the column Remarks using DataView, how do I do that? Thank you. Here's the code I'm working on:

```
ds.Tables["Grades"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { ds.Tables["Grades"].Columns["StudentID"] };
DataRow dRow = ds.Tables["Students"].Rows.Find(txtSearch.Text);

DataView dataView = new DataView(dt);
dataView.RowFilter = "Remarks = " + txtSearch.Text;
dgvReport.DataSource = dataView;
```

Comment: Note: it isn't necessary or desirable to put "C# winforms" in the question title.  That is what the tags are for.

Comment: How can you determine if the student is Passed or Failed in Column Remarks?is it you put Passed or Failed inside the column?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a LINQ query.

```
DataTable grades = dataSet.Tables["Grades"];

EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query = from grade in grades.AsEnumerable()
                                         where grade.Field<string>("Remarks") == "Failed"
                                         select grade;
DataView view = query.AsDataView();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with following code to get data in DataView based on your filter.

`DataRow[] drow= dt.Select("Remarks = " + txtSearch.Text);`

`DataTable dtFilterData = drow.copyToDataTable();`

`dgvReport.DataSource = new DataView(dtFilterData);`